# How to disassemble a Krome Dispense beer tower?

Tags: keg, kegerator

I have a beer tower whose lines need replacing.

But, I am having great trouble actually pulling the old lines out of the tower. They seem to be attached to some metal disks, which I can neither pull back through the tower, nor push through past the point where the faucets are attached. I can wiggle them around, but I can not actually dislodge them. The lines are stuck, dangling from the main body of the tower.

[image: partially disassembled beer tower]

Is there a trick to pulling the lines out of a tap like this?

The tower is a few years old, originally from Krome Dispense. [Fully assembled, the tower looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjqYd.jpg).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to buy a special tool that goes into those two half circles.  I don't see it in the tool list on pg 82/83 of the PDF that Eirikr posted.  I'd call KromeDispense and ask them.  OR email customer service with the tower part# if to you have it.  I am sure they'd help.

If you are handy or have a friend that does metal work they could probably make a tool that would work for you.  Splitting some metal rod and shaping two tips with the right distance.

Comment: Maybe get a flathead screwdriver and file down the center, leaving two prongs?

Comment: I've been trying with needle nose pliers. They can grip it, I just can't get it to go anywhere. We'll see how a specialized tool will do!

Answer (score 2):

I got it loose.

Trick wasn't a highly specialized tool (needle nose pliers did it), but having the protrusion on the clamp behind the metal disk precisely hit a notch. Then, the hose could be pulled up through the tower.

[image: Detached hose]

It was still stiff, and there was no telltale "click" that indicated it was correctly aligned. Just needed patience and trial and error. Lots of it.

By the way, the protrusions on the two clamps were *not* aligned with respect to the half-circle indents. One (pictured) was more or less perpendicular to the indents, the other was more to the side.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any direct knowledge, but you might find something useful by perusing the product list:

- http://kromedispense.com/KromeDispense.pdf

For instance, page 61 has pictures of a few different line configurations, which might help you figure out what's going on with yours.

Another option beyond reading is to chat with a company representative.  In the course of poking around, I happened upon Krome's [Knowledge Base page](https://us.kromedispense.com/knowledge-base/), where a chat window appears in the lower right.  I suspect they could help you.

Comment: The Knowledge Base looks like what I was looking for. Got stuck on the [more limited EU page](http://kromedispense.com/home.htm), which contains little but broken links when it comes to actually contacting them. Now I can get somewhere. :)